# Detect two scrolls on different button on android

Tags: android

Well, so, I have a view with two Button over all of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonno"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/red_button"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="NON"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonoui"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/green_buton"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="OUI"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

What I need is that the user is gonna touch BOTH buttons at the same time, but I need to detect if he/she is SCROLLING over the "ouiButton" or the "nonButton".

I have tried using onGestureListener, but it is not detecting anything.....anyone has any idea??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Button ouiButton = (Button) view.findByViewId(R.id.botonoui);
ouiButton.didTouchFocusSelect();
```

or

```
ouiButton.setOnGenericMotionListener(new OnGenericMotionListener() {
//Insert code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is not working. My main proble is to detect two touchs on the screen at the same time. I didn´t find anything where they explain how to detect two touchs on the screen at the same time....